# EXPRESSION - SQL Reporting Builder - Count & SUM to specific field

Tags: sql-server, count, ssrs-2008-r2

i try to sum a total into a different field if different condition. Please guide me to the correct way.

```
Product A       gender           total no. of male buy         total no. of female buy
   Buy           male                     1                              3
   Test          male
   Buy           female
   Buy           female
   Buy           female
```

any idea ? the result = total number male or female who "buy" the product A.
lease guide me to the correct way.
I'm using reporting builder 2008 r2, my knowledge on this builder limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't these values be at the end of the report? You cannot show sum of all rows in front of one of the rows itself, Its very misleading. Add Two rows outside the group at the end of the report and then use the following expressions to show counts.

**Expression For Male**

```
=Sum( 
   IIF( Fields!ProductA.Value = "Buy" AND Fields!gender.Value = "male", 1, 0)
   )
```

**Expression For Female**

```
=Sum( 
   IIF( Fields!ProductA.Value = "Buy" AND Fields!gender.Value = "Female", 1, 0)
   )
```

Comment: i do have another questing about this. can i ask u here ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457869/expression-sql-reporting-builder-2008-r2-how-to-sum-specific-field
=) please check M.Ali

Comment: You need to accept this answer as it answers the question you have asked here, than I will go to other question and answer that thank you.