# expression - sql reporting builder 2008 r2 - how to SUM specific field

Tags: sql-server, sum, ssrs-2008-r2

i have generated a table below:

```
No Product A|No Product B|No Product C|No Product D|total Product A+D|total Product B+D
    100           50           30           40               ?                  ?
```

in my first result, i wish to get the sum of total product A & D,
follow by total product B + D, and expression code can sum it accordingly ?

Comment: Why not calculate that on the SQL side, and then just display the column?

Comment: i donno about coding in SQL

Comment: do you have access to the underlying SQL that generates the results for your report?

Answer (score 1):

Again this is very simple , All you need is two expressions in your columns , it is just adding up two column. like you would do in sql server or any other RDBMS.

Add Two Columns to right of your existing columns and right click the data cell go to expression and use the following expressions to get the desired sum values.

**total Product A+D**

```
= Fields!ProductA.Value + Fields!ProductD.Value
```

**total Product B+D**

```
= Fields!ProductB.Value + Fields!ProductD.Value
```

I am only assuming the names of fields here, you will need to use the field name from your dataset. i.e  `Fields!YourFieldName.Value`

Comment: how if i created a normal text box for product A to D ? and i sum the value from others fields

Comment: Why would you use a textbox for this? what data region are you using?

Comment: You cannot mix two data regions in SSRS. one of the very painful limitations in ssrs.

Comment: i create sum of product A form a real field. there for , sum of product A = textbox

Comment: This is not how textboxes work in ssrs. every object on your design pane needs to be linked with only one dataset. two different objects like in this case a textbox and your report's Tablix can point to one dataset but values shown in textbox or tablix region are independent of each other, you cannot link them in any way. What wrong with just simply adding a column to the right and showing totals there?